# browser notification only once for all opened tabs per site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a news site that is powered by C# ASP.Net MVC 5.0 and I want to push notification to clients browser when an admin add/edit or delete a news.
so I added a signalr script to my template which is used in all pages.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
var notificationsHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
$.connection.hub.start();
jQuery(function($) {
    notificationsHub.client.Toast = function (title, body) {
        var options = {
            body: body,
        };
        var notification = new Notification(title, options);
    };
});
```

and added this code to the page that redirects after news add/edit/delete is done

```
<script>
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        notificationsHub.server.toast('@NotificationHub.Type.ToString()', '@Html.Raw(NotificationHub.Title)', '@Html.Raw(NotificationHub.Body)');
    });
</script>
```

when I add/edit/delete a news it works fine but the problem is it pushes notification to all opened tabs in my site. is there a trick to avoid this happening and show **only one** browser notification per site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928242/webkit-notifications-on-multiple-tabs).
The trick is to use `tag` in options:

```
var notificationsHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
$.connection.hub.start();
jQuery(function($) {
    notificationsHub.client.Toast = function (title, body) {
        var options = {
            body: body,
            tag: 'my-unique-id',
        };
        var notification = new Notification(title, options);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to know the number of open tabs and the URL used. See the "[How to get the number of tabs opened of my web in a browser using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972435/how-to-get-the-number-of-tabs-opened-of-my-web-in-a-browser-using-jquery)" SO question for a discussion that this is not desired for privacy reasons.

Comment: how knowing number of opened tabs of my site would help in this case?